# I need to create a list of numbers where each number relies on the previous number

Tags: python, for-loop

I need a list to be starting at 1, and each number after is 90% of the previous number. ex) 1,.9,.81,.729 etc. for (input) iterations. Needing it to be (input) iterations long leads me to believe I need to use a for loop so I could say

for i in range (1, N_steps): [where I later have N_steps = input("say n step")]

How can I do this?

What I have so far:

```
sl = []
for i in range (1, iti):
    sl = [1]
    sl[i+1] = sl[i] * .9
```

But I keep getting "list index out of range" error.

Comment: Have you tried thinking about the problem, developing an algorithm, testing the algorithm, refining it, and repeating the previous two steps until you arrive at a solution?

Comment: Are you asking me if I've tried figuring it out for myself? thanks for the help man

Comment: Work it out on paper first: break it down into small, simple steps that a computer could do, and take it one by one. Once you've gotten that together, translate your pseudocode algorithm into Python code structures.

Comment: I've tried working it out and couldn't that's why I'm here.
sl = []
    for i in range (1, iti):
        sl = [1]
        sl[i+1] = sl[i] * .9
is what it looks like at the moment but I keep getting "list index is out of range" error. also iti is an input

Comment: I think what Tigerhawk is trying to say is that we are here to help debug your code, not write it for you

Comment: How about showing us what you did? Maybe you were on the right track and just needed a small adjustment. As your question stands, the most specific answer anyone can give you is giving you the whole solution, which sometimes results in answers like the existing one.

Comment: Yeah I edited that comment to say what I did. It wasn't supposed to post at "I've tried working it out and couldn't that's why I'm here." I meant to shift+enter so I could show you what I had done

Comment: I added what I have to the question because it seems difficult to read in the comment

Comment: @TylerDavis you should never add additional information via a *comment*; since it belongs to the *question* it should go into the *question*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that, on each iteration of the loop, you set `sl` to a `list` with the single element `1`, and then immediately try to access other indices, which fails because the only valid index is `0` (or `-1`). Instead, use `append()` to add new elements to the `list` based on the last element, which has an index of `-1`:

```
sl = [1]
for i in range (1, iti):
    sl.append(sl[-1] * 0.9)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have gets you an out of bounds exception because you are looking ahead in the list where there is no element.

What you should do instead is make the list before the loop, then look backwards and add your new element.

```
sl = [1]
for i in range (1, iti):
    sl.append(sl[i-1] * .9)
```

Comment: Oh because there wasn't an i+1 to look to?

Comment: as in that element had not yet been filled?

Comment: @TylerDavis what value does `i` have in the first iteration? what is `sl[i]` supposed to be? are python indices zero-based or one-based?

Comment: @TylerDavis I believe I answered correctly first, but whatever

Answer (score -6):

```
reduce(lambda a, b: b * 0.9, [your_input_list], 1)
```